# C++: Deleting an Object in a static vector of pointers with the destructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, static, destructor

Here's how my class is set up:

```
class Foo{
    public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    static vector<Foo*> foos;
}

Foo::Foo(){
    foos.push_back(this);
}
Foo::~Foo(){}
```

Let's say I create an Object `Foo` like this:

```
int main(){
    Foo *obj = new Foo();
}
```

How would I go about deleting this object, as well as the pointer in the static vector?

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr` for both, then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You've got a couple of typos in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the implementation of `Foo::~Foo` to

```
Foo::~Foo()
{
    foos.erase(std::find(foos.begin(), foos.end(), this));
}
```

...use `std::unique_ptr`...

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr{new Foo{}};

    return 0;
}
```

... and it will clean up after itself.

Problems include:

- Not thread safe.
- A worst case time of *O(n)* per deletion for *n* instances.
- Evil global state!

If you're okay with the above, go ahead and pull the trigger!

Comment: How about storing an iterator as a member to prevent that O(n) time?

Comment: The backing store of `std::vector` is contiguous. In addition, iterators pointing to elements are invalidated after a container mutation. If an older element would need to be destroyed before a newer one, all pointers following its pointer in the vector would need to be shifted down. This is the _O(n)_ worst case.

Comment: @defube perhaps std::list can make it? "Addition, removal and moving the elements within the list or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators or references. An iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding element is deleted.", from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: Yep. Its still global state, though. Bear in mind, `std::list`, like any other node-based data structure, will need to poke its allocator with every mutation -- but you already knew that.